# Nvidia GPU not used

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, gpu

I've been trying to get my nvidia gpu (960m) to work on my arch install, but for now it doesn't.
I use the nvidia drivers. I ran nvidia-config, which modified my xorg.conf, as

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I don't really get where the issue is, but i believe it may have to do with the screen, or the monitor.
Lspci returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

If any of you have any idea of what i did wrong, please point it out, I'll be happy to correct it!

edit : 
By looking at Xorg log file, i found out that it was using Nouveau drivers, depsite the fact i uninstalled those, i guess for the integrated gpu, since it ran into what seems to be an error when loading nividia 
drivers :

```
 (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
```

any idea what that means ?

I found out that i had to have acpi installed (which was not), but also that i had to add it to the rc.conf file ? No idea what that is, and i don't seem to have one in /etc...

edit : I've already posted a similar question two weeks or so ago, but my internet went down, so i wasn't able to answer anything, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a 960m in my laptop and when first installing arch this was a massive pain to find all the resources i needed to fix it.
A good place to start is [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Use_NVIDIA_graphics_only)

My personal `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
Endsection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "1:0:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

In your post you showed that your bus id for the nvidia card was `01:00.0` for the X11 config we need to change it to look like `1:0:0`

Once you get your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` setup properly make sure to follow the instructions on the wiki page for your display manager of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using systemd, don't edit the `rc.conf` file (which probably doesn't even exist), instead you should 'start and/or enable the acpid.service' (which is how you enable daemon services properly in systemd), per [these](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid) [pages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACPI_modules) on the Arch Wiki. The Arch Wiki is an extremely helpful resource and I recommend you refer to it often.

You can also blacklist the nouveau kernel module by adding a file into the `/etc/modprobe.d` folder, per the instructions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting) (again from the Arch Wiki), so you can be assured it won't be used.